# How to change the URL, when modal is closed?

Tags: php, html, modal-dialog, yii2

I have tried to display the gridview with the modal.. For that I have used the pjax..
And the gridview has more data.. Show it shows the pagination. And pagination also working fine.

There is a problem, When I close the modal and refersh the page, Then the page totally changed .. Because the URL is refering the grid view pagination.

SO I have to change my url when the user closes the modal.. Is possible or not..

My Controller code is

```
     public function actionTotal()
     {

    $searchModel = new ServiceAccessSearch();


       $dataProvider=$searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams,1);        
            return $this->renderAjax('fullview',[
                    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            ]);
    }
```

my view code is

```
     <?=  GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'columns' => [
            'id',                                                                                                                                 
            'name',
            'status',

            ],
            'pjax' => true,
            'pjaxSettings' => ['options' => ['id' => 'kv-pjax-container']],                                                                       
            'export' => false,
            ]); ?>
```

Comment: You must disable pushState see documentation http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html#$enablePushState-detail

Comment: Yeah.. Its working Thank you..